# Set a specific color for new added cells in table

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table in which I add a new row or column by a position specified from input.I want only to that new rows and cells to change the color specified in a color picker.
I have this html

```
<label>Position</label>
        <input type="number" id="poz">
        <br />
        <label for="culoare">Color:</label>
        <input type="color" value="#ff0000" id="fundal" name="culoare"><br />
        <br />
        <button id="linie" onclick="insertRow();">Inserează linie</button>
        <button id="coloana" onclick="insertCol();">Inserează coloană</button>
        <br />
        <br />
        <table id="js-table">
            <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

These are the functions in javascript

```
function insertRow() {
var table = document.getElementById("js-table");
var len = document.getElementById("js-table").rows.length;
var val = document.getElementById("poz").value;
var culoare = document.getElementById("fundal").value;
var row = table.insertRow(val);
var cell=[];

for(let i = 0; i<len;i++)
{
    cell[i] = row.insertCell(i);
    cell[i].innerHTML = "New Row"+i;
}

}

function insertCol() {
var val = document.getElementById("poz").value;
var culoare = document.getElementById("fundal").value;
var firstRow = document.getElementById("js-table").rows[0];
var x = firstRow.insertCell(val);
x.innerHTML = "New Col";
}
```

The insert is made ok, but I don't know how to get that cells and change their color to the one specified in color picker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `x.style` and `background-color`.
So here the value of the color picker is in the `culoare` variable, so write `x.style = "background-color: " + culoare + ";";`
Here is you code:

```
function insertRow() {
  var table = document.getElementById("js-table");
  var len = document.getElementById("js-table").rows.length;
  var val = document.getElementById("poz").value;
  var culoare = document.getElementById("fundal").value;
  var row = table.insertRow(val);
  var cell=[];

  for(let i = 0; i<len;i++)
  {
      cell[i] = row.insertCell(i);
      cell[i].innerHTML = "New Row"+i;
      cell[i].style = "background-color: " + culoare + ";"; //Set the background color
  }
}

function insertCol() {
  var val = document.getElementById("poz").value;
  var culoare = document.getElementById("fundal").value;
  var firstRow = document.getElementById("js-table").rows[0];
  var x = firstRow.insertCell(val);
  x.innerHTML = "New Col";
  x.style = "background-color: " + culoare + ";"; //Set the background color
}
```

A live demo here: https://codepen.io/marchmello/pen/rNVEbXb?editors=0010

Comment: That was kind of simple, when I was typing x.style.background VS code didn't suggest me "background" and I thought it is not the right way.But thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `el.style.color` to set the color. This changes the CSS to create the color. Below is your revised code:

```
function insertRow() {
var table = document.getElementById("js-table");
var len = document.getElementById("js-table").rows.length;
var val = document.getElementById("poz").value;
var culoare = document.getElementById("fundal").value;
var row = table.insertRow(val);
var cell=[];

for(let i = 0; i<len;i++)
{
    cell[i] = row.insertCell(i);
    cell[i].innerHTML = "New Row"+i;
}

}

function insertCol() {
var val = document.getElementById("poz").value;
var culoare = document.getElementById("fundal").value;
var firstRow = document.getElementById("js-table").rows[0];
var x = firstRow.insertCell(val);
x.innerHTML = "New Col";
x.style.color = culoare;
}
```